# How to display values from Navigation Property collections in MVC Index page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an EF Entity Type named 'JobTitle' which has a Navigation Property named 'Offices'(which is a collection of another Entity Type named 'Office').

I would like to display a list of JobTitle names and related Office names in my Index view.
The View scaffolding has generated the following by default:

```
@model IEnumerable<Example.Models.JobTitle>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitleName)
        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitleName)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My controller code (by default) looks like:

```
    // GET: /JobTitle/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.JobTitles.ToList());
    }
```

This will allow me to generate all of the simple properties that belong to 'JobTitle' (such as 'JobTitleName'). However I cannot work out how to retrieve the corresponding 'Office' information from the 'Offices' collection (Navigation Property) into my view.

So, I am hoping to end up with a display of two columns, 'JobTitle' and 'Office'.

(In my database these entities are represented by three tables: JobTitle (JobTitleID,JobTitleName), Office (OfficeID,OfficeName) and JobTitleOffice (JobTitleID,OfficeID))

I am completely new to MVC and Entity Framework, so any help gratefully received.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the future, with questions like this, it's best if you post your actual entity classes. However, based on your tables, it looks like you have a many-to-many relationship between `JobTitle` and `Office`. Your difficulty is most likely related to how to access the `OfficeName` property for a particular `JobTitle` instance, and the problem there is that there's not just one `OfficeName`, but many. You need to iterate over the list of `Office`s.

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitleName)
    @foreach (var office in item.Offices)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => office.OfficeName)
    }
</td>
```

If you want a slightly better display, you might want to turn the names of the offices into a comma-delimited list (e.g., `Office Name 1, Office Name 2, ...`) which can be achieved by doing the following instead of using the foreach:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitleName)
    @string.Join(", ", item.Offices.Select(m => m.OfficeName))
</td>
```

Or, if you only care about showing a single office name, you can use `FirstOrDefault` to pull out a single office:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitleName)
    @{
        var office = item.Offices.FirstOrDefault();
        if (office != null)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => office.OfficeName);
        }
    }
</td>
```

You should always check for `null` first, just in case there's actually no related offices.

Basically, which method you choose simply depends on your application's requirements. Also, pay attention to Entity Framework's lazy loading of related items. Here it's not so bad, as the first time you try to access `Offices`, a single new query will be issued to fetch the related offices. Since, you're not trying to access any related properties off of `Office`, that one extra query won't affect much. But consider the following:

```
public class Office
{
    ...

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

If you tried to do something like:

```
@foreach (var office in item.Offices)
{
    @office.OfficeName
    <address>
        @office.Address.Street
        ...
    </address>
}
```

You'd end up with what's called an N+1 query, where you have one query to fetch the collection (`Offices`) and then one query to fetch the `Address` for *each* office (resulting in `N` queries, where `N` is the total number of offices). In this type of situation, you're better off eager-loading. For example,

```
return View(db.JobTitles.Include("Offices.Address").ToList());
```

That would cause Entity Framework to do a join to include both `Offices` and each `Address` for each `Office` instance all in the query to fetch the job titles. You could then do whatever you wanted with any of this information without worrying about multiple additional queries being issued.

Answer (score 0):

You can project the result into collection of `JobTitleName` and `OfficeName` using [**`SelectMany`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [**`Select`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitleName)</th>
        <th>Office</th>
    </tr>

    @{
        var items = Model
            .SelectMany(j => j.Offices
                .Select(o => new { j.JobTitleName, o.OfficeName }));
    }
    @foreach (var item in items) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitleName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfficeName)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**PS**

The `Offices` collection will automatically be loaded (when the foreach is executed) if you have `virtual` keyword on the navigation property and use the default configuration (proxy + lazy loading). This is called lazy loading.

```
public class JobTitle
{
    // other properties
    public string JobTitleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Office> Offices { get; set; }
}
public class Office
{
    // other properties
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobTitle> JobTitles { get; set; }
}
```

More

- [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)
- [Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)