# How can I show the property of a related entity in a grid column?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a EF class named `City` (which corresponds to a database table)

```
public partial class 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Edit { get; set; }
    public string Delete { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

I have another EF class called `V_STATUS`, which corresponds to a database view:

```
public partial class V_STATUS
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string TITLE{ get; set; }
}
```

In the MVC view where the grid is created, I want to show the `title` from `V_STATUS` joined on the `status` from `City`:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 form-group">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => {
        columns.Add(m => m.Title).Titled("Title");
        columns.Add(m => m.PostalCode ).Titled("PostalCode");
        // INSTEAD OF m=> m.status to be shown title from v_status
        columns.Add(m=> m.status).Titled("Status");
        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50).RenderValueAs(r =>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateCity", new { id = r.id })
        );
        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(r =>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCity", new { id = r.id })
        );
    }).WithPaging(5).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
</div>
```

Comment: And don't dump your entire view when asking a question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NormalHuman I've edited the all-caps; consider deleting your comment.

Comment: post your controller...you need the controller to return the joined data set

Answer (score 0):

You need to include relationship between `City` and `V_Status` by changing status property as `virtual` property.

include virual property:

```
public virtual V_STATUS Status { get; set; }
```

> Code:

```
public partial class City
{
    //Existing propertites
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Edit { get; set; }
    public string Delete { get; set; }

    //Modified property
    public virtual V_STATUS Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here we go for UI:

**Your code:**

```
// INSTEAD OF m=> m.status to be shown title from v_status
        columns.Add(m=> m.status).Titled("Status");
```

**Try this:**

```
 columns.Add(m=> m.Status.Title).Titled("Status");//included navigation property Title
```

Note:

1. You have told that V_Status is database view. So you may need to
   `ignore` that property from City  through
   Fluent API or Data Annotation.
2. If you want to use one to many relationship you need to use for loop in View page.

**References to Show Navigation property values in UI:**
[So Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609982/how-to-display-values-from-navigation-property-collections-in-mvc-index-page)

[Article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Consider accept the answer if it helps.